Google workspace add-on install trigger with toolbar failed
It is very weird! The same code(attached below), user take diff installation ways, diff effects.
Success situation:
User A -> click menu item in Add-on menu to install trigger(Google sheet onEdit trigger).
User A can call that trigger when edit something in sheet.
All other users can call that trigger when edit something in sheet.
Failure situation:
User -> click the button in the sidebar by the toolbar icon to install the same trigger.
User A can call that trigger when edit something in sheet.
All other users cannot call that trigger when edit something in sheet.
The permissions for all users above are the same, editors.
Error screenshot
Show you the code:
function onOpen(e) {
  menu.addItem('Sync this sheet', 'createSpreadsheetEditTrigger').addToUi()
}
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  let myInstallTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit_recordChanges')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
      .onEdit()
      .create()
}
function onEdit_recordChanges(e) {
  Logger.log('Done')
}

function onHomepage(e) {
  const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
  const section = CardService.newCardSection()
  section.addWidget(CardService.newDecoratedText().setText('Let\'s make it sync!').setWrapText(true).setButton(CardService.newTextButton().setText('Sync').setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
.setFunctionName("createSpreadsheetEditTrigger"))))
  card.addSection(section)
  return card.build()
}

{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Shanghai",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "JIRA sync test",
      "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-3LidxlBrmxk/ZgJMNMPA-iI/AAAAAAAAA88/wGRTTurlphEGRJC0sWoox55XDnZiUm4LwCNcBGAsYHQ/s72-c/jira-32.jpg",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "orange",
        "secondaryColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "onHomepage"
      },
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "onHomepage"
      }
    },
    "docs": {}
  }
}

I'm wondering why it failed. And there's no any logs and it shows 0s like no permission to run.

First you should be aware that you are mixing code for an Editor add-on and code for a Workspace add-on.
Not all the features that work on one type of account works on the other, i.e., the CardService only works for Workspace add-ons, and simple triggers, like onOpen, only works for Editor add-on.
Each type add-on has it's own install and authorization life-cycle but might share some resources like the Google Cloud project associated to the Google Apps Script project.
When working with multiple users on the same file, in this case a spreadsheet, you should ensure that all the users are editors of the spreadsheet to be able to run scripts and the editor add-on should be enabled on the spreadsheet.
When working with installable triggers, during testing and debugging, set the error notification to send it immediately, otherwise you might have to wait to the next day to get error notification.
Regarding Logger it writes logs to the Execution Log. When working with add-ons you might want to take of console which also writes logs to into the Google Cloud Platform logging service.

It seems you know deeply on the Editor add-on and Workspace add-on.
This 2 situation test with the same accounts. It means all the users are the editors and are able to run the script. The only different is the way to create the trigger by the trigger creator (by Menu or Sidebar).

@Esone As comments are not intended for extended discusiones, please posts a more focused follow up question, but first make a [mcve] with no Editor add-on code to reproduce the problem including the execution logs.
